# Forms Authentication 4.0 on Web Farm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

This is quite literally driving me bananas - I'm on holiday as from tomorrow but if I can't get this working today then it's under threat - so any help much appreciated!

Firstly, my website has a manually defined `<machinekey />` element defined so that both web servers in the web farm are kept in sync.  I have verified this with IIS manager (hence why I'm asking, despite the similarity with so many other questions).  It looks like this (keys elided - but they are the correct length):

```
<machineKey validationKey="[512 bit hex]" 
    decryptionKey="[256-bit hex]" 
    validation="SHA1" 
    decryption="AES" />
```

The website is running Asp.Net MVC3 and I am using Forms authentication in 'normal' mode (i.e. not 2.0 compat mode).  I'm using Forms Authentication to create an authentication ticket - using code like the following:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```

My Forms Auth config is very simple; there are no IIS or server-wide settings in place that override the documented defaults:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/Unauthorised" 
   loginUrl="~/Unauthorised" 
   ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" />
</authentication>
```

And then I've hijacked the cookie-reading functionality [as per this MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.authenticate.aspx) so that I can create the principal and identity that I want.

Problem is - only one half of the web farm is able to decrypt the authentication cookie, the other half (i.e. whichever one didn't authenticate the user) just gives:

`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.`

With this as the top-part of the stack trace:

```
[CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.]
System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount) +12521039
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock() +53
System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType) +331
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(String encryptedTicket) +293
```

We are using a slightly ancient (but very reliable) Load balancer - which *does not modify* the HTTP traffic - and the traffic in this case is HTTPs; I'm able to verify that it's always one server and not both by having used Fiddler to decrypt and inspect the traffic.

This clearly points to out-of-sync `machineKey`s - but they are not - so any idea what's going on!!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check your patches? http://blog.evonet.com.au/post/SystemSecurityCryptographyCryptographicException-Length-of-the-data-to-decrypt-is-invalid.aspx

Comment: @Surfer513 - put up an answer; I'm not sure yet - but talking to one of the support team it might be the cause...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When different servers have different patches, it has the potential to alter the behavior of encryption (/decryption), therefore possibly causing this runtime exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.
```

More information regarding this issue can be found here: http://blog.evonet.com.au/post/SystemSecurityCryptographyCryptographicException-Length-of-the-data-to-decrypt-is-invalid.aspx

Comment: @Surfer512 - There were so many updates that one of the machines has got to be done overnight (let's just say it had ten times as many required as on the other one...) - so I'll be able to update then.  Cheers!

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"This site can’t be reached / blog.evonet.com.au’s server DNS address could not be found"*